# Elm to manage a particular section of a site

Tags: elm

Hi I am new to elm and would like to know if it would be possible to set up elm such that it manages only one section of a website. the rest of the site would be in plain javascript, html, css.

but i would like to load up the compiled elm app in a separate script tag and it should manage only a particular section

let us say that the website is divided into 10 divs vertically of height 300px. i would want only the 3rd div to be an elm app.

is such a thing possible? if so how can i get this working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Html` packages `embed` function for this. I once did this just to try it out, but unfortunately cannot recall any details of it. I did found some source code though.

The html page would be something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="personnel"></div>
  </body>

  <script src="elm.js"></script>
  <script>
    Elm.Person.embed(document.getElementById('personnel'));
  </script>
</html>
```

By including elm.js, you'll get the Elm runtime. Here `Person` is my compiled Elm module. Something like

```
module Person exposing (..)

-- Module details here...

main =
  Html.beginnerProgram { model = init, view = view, update = update }
```

Elm code is compiled to JavaScript with command

```
elm-make Person.elm --output elm.js
```

My knowledge on this is quite limited, but I did investigate it enough to be certain that with by doing this, one can add multiple components made with Elm to an html page / existing application.

**Addendum:** I found the [source of my information](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html)

Comment: is there a way to also remove the elm module from javascript? something like Elm.Person.unmount()? or destroy()?

Comment: @Imraan what is your use case for removing the Elm module? What if you removed the div where the module is added?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer perhps you would like to take a look on:
https://ellie-app.com/h7vqHrPdWa1/0